# How to develop a new IoTAgent

Tags: node.js, fiware

I'm developing a new IoT Agent according to https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/index.html

and I'm trying to run the following code: node index.js

but a warning shows up: (node:6176) [DEP0097] DeprecationWarning: Using a domain property in MakeCallback is deprecated. Use the async_context variant of MakeCallback or the AsyncResource class instead.
DEP0097 - Deprecation Warning (NODE.JS)

Any suggestions how to solve it?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are running your IoT Agent under **Node 14**. The Domain API has been [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) and this is the cause of your warning. There is [code](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/lib/services/common/domain.js) within the IoT Agent Node lib currently uses the Domain API for communications with Telefonica Steelskin.

The IoT Agents are tested against LTS node releases, (currently 10 and 12 see [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/.travis.yml)) and Node 14 doesn't hit LTS until October 2020, so I would expect an interim release should fix the issue.

In the meantime if you run your agent under an earlier version of Node - for example via Docker. An example can be found in the Custom IoT Agent [tutorial](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Custom-IoT-Agent) Dockerfile

```
ARG  NODE_VERSION=10.17.0-slim
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}


COPY . /opt/iotXML/

WORKDIR /opt/iotXML

RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    npm install pm2@3.2.2 -g && \
    echo "INFO: npm install --production..." && \
    npm install --production && \
    # Remove Git and clean apt cache
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get remove -y git && \
    apt-get -y autoremove && \
    chmod +x docker/entrypoint.sh

USER node
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Expose 4041 for NORTH PORT, 7896 for HTTP PORT
EXPOSE ${IOTA_NORTH_PORT:-4041} ${IOTA_HTTP_PORT:-7896}

ENTRYPOINT ["docker/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["-- ", "config.js"]
```

The node version can be altered by adding `NODE_VERSION` to the Docker build command when building the Docker container.

Comment: Hello Jason, Thank you for the response. I downgrade node to version 8 and it solved the warning. I tried to follow the Custom IoT Agent tutorial Dockerfile https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Custom-IoT-Agent but when I tried to run command ./services create a message ERROR: pull access denied for fiware/iotagent-xml, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

Comment: You can also `cd iot-agent` and `Docker build -t iotagent-xml .` if the script isn't working for you. The error may be to do with your Docker version or docker-compose version

Comment: I typed **docker-compose -v** and **docker version** as mentioned in the tutorial. Here is the result: 
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b.
docker version: 19.03.5
I'm running docker toolbox on windows 10, I don't know if it's the problem.
I tried  **cd  iot-agent** and **docker build -f Dockerfile -t renatobdo/iotagent-xml .**

Comment: I changed the name of image from service iot-agent on docker-compose.yml to **renatobdo/iotagent-xml** because
I don't have permission to push into fiware/iotagent-xml dockerhub and the image fiware/iotagent-xml doesn't exist on 
dockerhub.
I pushed on my repository renatobdo/iotagent-xml it's public.
I executed **./services create** from https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Custom-IoT-Agent 
and **./services start** and it worked. However, I don't know why the image **renatobdo/iotagent-xml** is not running.

Comment: So command
**curl -X GET \ 'http://192.168.99.100:4041/iot/about'** doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with docker for windows toolbox. I installed linux and the custom iot agent worked. I think the problem ocurred because of  the environment variables. For some reason windows 10 doesn't initiate .env archive variables that exist in the project.